# Using procmail to trigger applications to run on my computer... But I hit a snag

Tags: linux, shell, x11, procmail

I wanted to make a setup where if I recieve an email, applications would run automatically.
I got the Email and fetchmail setup working, but I seem to be getting problems with the execution of the linux commands themselves.

Here is the Procmail code:

```
:0
* ^Subject: .*Subject
| xrandr --size 1360x768;\
  firefox "link"; \
  timeout 2m recordmydesktop; \
  xrandr --size 1366x768
```

This is the error:

```
(process:3611): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed
Error: no display specified
No display specified for connection!
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer.

I just needed to add this line just before the other scripts.
    export DISPLAY=:0.0; \

Whole code:

```
:0
* ^Subject: .*subject!
| export DISPLAY=:0.0; \
   xrandr --size 1360x768;\
   firefox "***"; \
   timeout 150m recordmydesktop; \
   xrandr --size 1366x768
```